# Check Dependencies Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I apologize if this is the incorrect community for this question. Please redirect me if needed.

I have a piece of software that I need to check what all dependencies are required. I have seen Dependency Walker but according to their website :

> runs on Windows 95, 98, Me, NT, 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 7, and 8

I need a (trustworthy) solution for Windows 10 that will list all dependencies. Ideally this would detail the location as well.

**EDIT**

Looking into [this](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) currently

Comment: All software on Windows contains a manifest. Its there that all dependencies are listed.  Look up assembly loader for windows and .net.  Dependency walker works but not for .net or java. There's different software for that... or write your own.